# Grep value between strings with regex

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

```
$ acpi

Battery 0: Charging, 18%, 01:37:09 until charged
```

How to grep the battery level value without percentage character (18)?

This should do it but I'm getting an empty result:

```
acpi | grep -e '(?<=, )(.*)(?=%)'
```

Comment: Use `grep -oP '(?<=, )[^%]+(?=%)'`

Comment: or `grep -oP 'Charging, \K\d+'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is correct but will work with *experimental* `-P` or `perl mode regex option` in `gnu grep`. You will also need `-o` to show only matching text.

Correct command would be:

```
grep -oP '(?<=, )\d+(?=%)'
```

However, if you don't have `gnu grep` then you can also use `sed` like this:

```
sed -nE 's/.*, ([0-9]+)%.*/\1/p' file
```

```
18
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
 awk -F"," '{print $2+0}'
```

Using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -rn 's/.*\, *([0-9]+)\%\,.*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested in link https://ideone.com/nzSGKs

```
your_command | awk 'match($0,/Charging, [0-9]+%/){print substr($0,RSTART+10,RLENGTH-11)}'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above only for explanation purposes.

```
your_command |                              ##Running OP command and passing its output to awk as standrd input here.
awk '                                       ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/Charging, [0-9]+%/){              ##Using match function to match regex Charging, [0-9]+% in line here.
  print substr($0,RSTART+10,RLENGTH-11)     ##Printing sub string and printing from 11th character from starting and leaving last 11 chars here in matched regex of current line.
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
$ acpi | sed -nE 's/.*Charging, ([[:digit:]]*)%.*/\1/p'
18
```

Or, if `Charging` is not always in the string, you can look for the `,`:

```
$ acpi | sed -nE 's/[^,]*, ([[:digit:]]*)%.*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```sh
s='Battery 0: Charging, 18%, 01:37:09 until charged'
res="${s#*, }"
res="${res%%%*}"
echo "$res"
```

Result: `18`.

`res="${s#*, }"` removes text from the beginning to the first `comma+space` and `"${res%%%*}"` removes all text from end till (and including) the last occurrence of `%`.